# Escaping code in HTML with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular application where several departments are returning some bad characters in the data. In particular, one of our division codes is coming back as `%L` when it really should be `%25L`. If I use the Javascript escape function in my services it fixes the data as it goes BACK to the database. However, I still have the problem in my views where we use:

```
{{ Case.DivisionCode }}
```

We use that value to build a URL and the %`L` is breaking the code. Is there a way to do something like escape() on that value in the HTML?

Comment: why don't you correct it in the controller?

Comment: can't you use a custom filter?

Comment: While I understand that this is an issue, the fix should really happen on the back end. Whatever is sending the data should fix it there. Maybe it's encoded incorrectly in your DB, maybe the server is mangling it, maybe it was inserted incorrectly, whatever the case, you need to find it there because front end patches will not fix the actual problem

Comment: Correcting it in the controller would mean fixing the entire model which can have a large number of records. Not sure that would be very efficient. I agree that it should probably be handled in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in the controller something like following:

```
$scope.Case.DivisionCode = escape($scope.Case.DivisionCode);
```

assuming that you have a function in the controller called 'escape'

Comment: Here is the problem. Say you get a model called "Case" and it has all the data to be used in the view. You don't want to have to escape every single value in the model to handle this because it means essentially recreating the model in a new array.

Comment: well, you can just loop through the array and you escape the ones contain the "bad data" only. you don't change the original data passed to this controller anyway, but if you want to make sure you can just clone it to another empty array if you want to make sure:

var newArray = [];

$scope.Case.DivisionCode.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item === 'BADDATA') {
        newArray.push(escape(item));
    } else {
        newArray.push(item);
    }
});

It's always better to handle such things on the client side, the computers are powerful, and you don't cause additional load to server.

Comment: And you can use {{ newArray }} in html. One more thing the newArray should be $scope.newArray of course above.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, I think you may want to look into [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) and the [Strict Contextual Escaping service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) for this.  They provide the functionality of the escape/encodeURI method, but in an angular context.